# breakpoints window in xcode 4 IOS4.3

Tags: xcode4, debugging, ios4

I just downloaded xcode 4 with IOS 4.3 and trying to run my app on it. I have set some breakpoints and I can imagine that the code is currently stopped at a breakpoint, as the initial screen of the app has not come up and the breakpoint is before that. But I cannot see the source code are where the breakpoint is stopped. I also cannot see the single step/ continue buttons which were so easy with the old debugger. How can I open the debugger to see where my code position is right now? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xcode4, the breakpoint window is located in the navigator view on the left. You can open it by pressing `[cmd + 6]` or with this button

[image: Breakpoint view]

The debug area is located at the bottom of your screen, open it via `[cmd + shift + Y]` or with this button

[image: Debug area]

In the debug area, you will also find the buttons for stepping trough your code

[image: Debug buttons]

Hope this helps!